How did telegraph operators ensure they received the intended message? Was some sort of checksum used?
Assuming the operators were using Morse code (un-encrypted or otherwise) how could the receiver determine they got the correct message?

Important messages were repeated... not good enough?

I think you might want to be a bit clearer about the timeframe. You using "some sort of checksum" in your question title suggests you're already considering computerized machines, but the coexistence of commercial "Morse operators" and computers in telecommunication was brief, mostly because Morse is a "stupidly suboptimal" system in anything but humans communicating directly, so computers talking to computers (and these are the only things that can easily calculate and check checksums) would not use Morse in a system designed sensibly, from a technical point of view. So, which decades?

(I'm also assuming you mean commercial telegraphy, not military communications; different militaries used to have different signaling rules, and I'd guess that confirmation rules (and shapes) would differ pretty substantially, too. Tragically, the world saw two world wars during the relatively short time that Morse was of technical relevance, so in practice, a lot of how Morse was done and, more importantly to your question, regulated, might have had a warfare background :( )

Good stuff!
Someone was scheduled to sit at the station and await messages. It was a two way communication so the person on the receiving end could acknowledge and await the message. Each "send" started with a code so the receiver could listen for their stations ID. (town and state name) Much like computers with "handshakes" to ACK (acknowledge). They would basically say in their lingo, I am here, go ahead. There were also machines that had tape in them that would print out the dots and dashes from the code much like a mass broadcast. You can see samples of both ways in a lot of old black and white movies. Morse code becomes a second language once you use it enough. So just listening they could here their station being hailed. Many stations used the same lines. (no privacy!)
Important messages that were sent were requested to be verified.
On the link below, you can see a lot of information about it starting at
Transmitting or Sending
https://morsetelegraphclub.org/library/files/html/dodge/dodge.html#transmitting_or_sending

Repitition, verification, duplicate receiving (via ticker tape as well as pad or mill).  +1
